# How to make dynamic detail views in xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, detailview

I have a table view with a bunch of words of varying parts of speech. Currently I have a detail view that only has the correct layout for nouns. As I see it there are two options. 1: Have a single dynamic detail view that changes based on the part of speech or 2: have multiple detail views that each correspond to a part of speech. When a word is selected it brings up the detail view with the correct layout for that part of speech.

I'm using swift

[image]

This is the detail view I currently have. It is only correct for nouns. For a verb I could reuse the TitleLabel and the SubtitleLabel but the declension and gender labels wouldn't apply. There are also other labels such as conjugation and transitivity that only apply to verbs and not to nouns. The language I'm using is latin if anyone cares

Comment: Without seeing what you want your other views to look like, I'd say it's probably easier to go with option 2 and have a detail view for each part of speech.  You could have a different prototype cell for each part of speech.  That way you could wire up the segues in Interface Builder.

Comment: Ok. I have read more about prototype cells now. My table holds all the values in an array. First I add nouns to the array then verbs. Would I just use the same array to hold them but when creating the cell object use the reuseIdentifier specific to that part of speech.

Comment: Exactly.  Use a different reuse identifier for each part of speech.

Comment: You could, if it makes sense, put each part of speech in its own section of the table.  In that case, it would probably make more sense to have an array for each part of speech.

Comment: Well I want it to be alphabetical and not sorted by what type of word it is. But thats another issue

Comment: You could if you wanted make each part of speech its own color so that they could tell at a glance when looking at the table.